# Storing view counter and total minutes watched to DB using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, ajax, servlets

need help to store view counter and total minutes watched to SQL db using javaScript, Servlets and the db controller class.

the parts i have completed is below but it doesn't seem to work.

I've tested the db handler part it worked properly, feel like the problem is sending the values from javascript to servlet.

this is the JS part:

```
<script>
  var video = document.getElementById("video+<%=rs.getString(5)%>");
  var timeStarted = -1;
  var timePlayed = 0;
  var duration = 0;
  var viewcount = 0;
  var fired = false;

  if (video.readyState > 0)
    getDuration.call(video);
  else {
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',
      getDuration);
  }
  function videoStartedPlaying() {
    timeStarted = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

  }

  function videoStoppedPlaying(event) {
    if (timeStarted > 0) {
      var playedFor = new Date().getTime() / 1000
        - timeStarted;
      timeStarted = -1;
      timePlayed += playedFor;
      if (event.type == "ended"
        || event.type == "paused") {
        saveDb();
      }

    }

    document.getElementById("played").innerHTML = Math
      .round(timePlayed)
      + "";

    if ((timePlayed > 3 || event.type == "ended")
      && (!fired)) {
      viewcount += 1;
      document.getElementById("views").innerHTML = viewcount;

      if (event.type == "ended"
        || event.type == "paused") {
        saveDb();
      }
    }

    fired = true;

    if (event.type == "ended") {
      fired = false;
    }

  }

  function saveDb() {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'addAnalytics',
      data: {
        videoid:<%=rs.getString(5) %>,
        time: timePlayed,
        views: viewcount
      },
      type: 'GET'
    });
  }

  function getDuration() {
    duration = video.duration;
    console.log("Duration: ", duration);
  }

  video.addEventListener("play", videoStartedPlaying);
  video.addEventListener("playing", videoStartedPlaying);

  video.addEventListener("ended", videoStoppedPlaying);
  video.addEventListener("pause", videoStoppedPlaying);
</script>
```

this is the servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {

        dbcontroller db = new dbcontroller();
        int vidid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("videoid"));
        int vcount = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("views"));
        int wtime = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("time"));

        int stat = db.saveAnalytics(vidid, vcount, wtime);

        if (stat != -1) {
            response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        }
        return;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this is the db handler:

```
public int saveAnalytics(int id, int viewcount, int time) {
    int totViews, totDuration;
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps1 = connection
            .prepareStatement("SELECT videoViews, totalTime FROM video WHERE videoId=" + id);
        ResultSet rs = ps1.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            int views = rs.getInt("videoViews");
            int duration = rs.getInt("totalTime");


            totViews = views + viewcount;
            totDuration = duration + time;

            PreparedStatement ps = connection
                .prepareStatement("update video set videoViews=? ,totalTime=? WHERE videoId=?");

            ps.setInt(1, totViews);
            ps.setInt(2, totDuration);
            ps.setInt(3, id);

            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: does ajax send proper data ? does the servlet get called with those request param ?

Comment: I'm trying to access the servlet when the video is played, paused and ended, not quite sure wether its possible

Comment: do you receive values in servlet ?

Comment: okay the servlet its not getting called properly

Comment: the values are null

Comment: Intercept ajax request in browser, see whats going on

Comment: no ajax requests happening, when i intercepted

Comment: Hey thanks a lot managed to fix it, made some silly mistakes, forgot to add the jquery library and the Ajax code was in the wrong position.